# How to recover from uninstall of gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock

I wanted to disable the always-visible dock that comes with the Ubuntu 17.10 version of gnome shell. I found tips to either install the dash-to-dock extensions or to just uninstall the Ubuntu dock extension. The first resulted in two overlapping docks, the latter in removing several other packages. The Ubuntu shell theme is broken now and the dock is still always visible and stuck in a broken theme.

Obviously, messing with the default extensions without fully installing vanilla gnome was a bad idea. Do you know how to undo the changes? I already re-installed the ubuntu-desktop package but that didn't fix anything so it wasn't the only one removed along with gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read the files in `/var/log/apt/*`, and you can reconstruct the install/reinstall/whatever path you took to get to your current situation.
Trace this path in reverse.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the logs, only ubuntu-desktop was removed along with gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock. I already reinstalled ubuntu-desktop, which seems to be a tiny wrapper package. The issues with the Ubuntu gnome shell theme and the dock haven't been resolved, though.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Dock is a fork of Dash to Dock, so installing and running both at the same time might cause problems. If you want Dash to Dock only, follow these steps.

**Uninstall Ubuntu Dock**

- Open the terminal and run these commands:

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
>
> $ rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
> ```

- Reboot.

**Install Dash to Dock**

- Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/ and install the extension by clicking on the On/Off button. You might need to install Firefox or Chrome GNOME extensions plugin